# Overlapping two grid items not working as expected

Tags: html, css, sass

So I've been trying to overlap grid `2` over grid `1` without using negative `margins` but I'm unable to do so please help

Here's my code

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="HeaderContainerGrid">
      <img src="./svg/background.svg" />
      <header>
        <h1>Guideline</h1>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**styles.scss**

```
@import './variables';

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

header {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  display: grid;
  align-items: end;
  justify-content: end;
  h1 {
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 1em;
  }
  nav {
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }

  ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
  }
  li {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    &:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: $secondaryColor;
      transition: 0.5s;
      color: $onHoverTextColor;
    }
  }
}

.HeaderContainerGrid {
    display: grid;
    &:nth-child(1) {
        background-color: red;
        grid-row: 1 / 2;
        z-index: 1
    }
    &:nth-child(0) {
        grid-row: 1 / 2;
        z-index: -1
    }
}
```

[CodeSandbox URL](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-night-6gj5e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `header` position `absolute` so that it will come out from its normal flow and come over the nearest `relative` position.

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-brown-527oi?file=/styles/styles.css)

```
header{
 position: absolute;
}

.HeaderContainerGrid {
  position: relative;
}
```